# Submit a form in vue. How do I reference the form element?

Tags: vue.js

I want to do a classic form submission from my Vue page, from a method. I don't want to use an `<input type="submit">`. How do I reference the form element in the page from my method? Surely I don't have to do `document.getElementById()` ?

**markup**

```html
    <div id="vueRoot">
      <form>
        <input name="vitalInformation" v-model="store.vital">
        <a href="#" v-on:click="submit">SUBMIT</a>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**code**

```js
    var store = {vital:''};
    vm = new Vue({
      el : "#vueRoot",
      data : {store : store},
      methods : {
        submit : function(){
          //I'm ready, how do I do it ??
        }
      }
    });
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/5upmvLkb/)**

Comment: I'm curious, why don't you want use input type=submit?

Comment: Or `@submit="method()"`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The answer would be: `ref`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

#### Markup

```
<div id="vueRoot">
  <form ref="form">
    <input name="vitalInformation" v-model="store.vital">
    <a href="#" v-on:click="submit">SUBMIT</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

### code

```
var store = {vital:''};
vm = new Vue({
  el : "#vueRoot",
  data : {store : store},
  methods : {
    submit : function(){
      this.$refs.form.$el.submit()
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it says ````this.$refs.form.submit()```` is not a function

Comment: can i send data as well when i am submitting the form?

Comment: not like this. The above method simply submits the form just like it would when you click the submit button of a form on a static HTML site, which eans it will send a POST request with all the fields' content already.

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan, the correct way is `this.$refs.form.$el.submit()`. `vm.$el` will give you access to the actual dom element

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan and others getting `is not a function` or `is undefined`, remember to add `ref="form"` to the form element too.

Comment: It is submitting, but I have @submit.prevent on the form, in order to validate each field in html5 validations, but it is avoiding the prevent.

Comment: @LinusBorg You should probably change this to [`form.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit#Usage_notes) instead, so any form validation and vue event handlers can also fire. (cc @ AndresFelipe's)

Comment: @phil294: I had the same issue regarding using `@submit.prevent`. Your fix to use `form.requestSubmit()` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Sorry for the late reply, but I am confused why you need `ref` when submitting a form.

```js
data: function(){
  return {
   name: "",
   price: "",
  }
},
methods: {
  addProduct(e){
    e.preventDefault() // Prevent page from reloading.
    // console.log(this.name, this.price);
  }
}
```

```html
<form v-on:submit="addProduct">
  <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="Product Name" >
  <input type="number" v-model="price" placeholder="Price">
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer makes the most sense.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is trigger the event `click()`.

```
<button ref="submit" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
```

In your function call it as follows:

```
this.$refs.submit.click();
```

Comment: With forms, it's nearly always better to attach to the submit event instead of click. Not only is it better for accessibility, it also allows hitting <enter> to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

From above answers I used following statements

```
this.$refs.form.submit()
this.$refs.submit.click();
```

both throw following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$refs' of null
```

I'm able to fix this issue by storing $refs in a variable then access the relevant method

if you want to use ref for form submit event

```
 const form = this.$refs.formRef
 form.submit()
```

if you want to use ref for other element's event like click

```
 const btn = this.$refs.btnRef
 btn.click()
```

Comment: That is very strange. `this` should never be null. I have never had to assign things to a variable to access.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where it says that `submit is not a function`
It looks like if a form control has a name or id of submit it will mask the form's submit method.
In my case I had `name="submit"` on my submit button, I removed it and it worked fine.