# How to get element using vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have form like this

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="save_data(this)"></form>
```

and function like this

```
methods: {
   save_data: function(f){

   }
}
```

on jquery we can get form like this

```
$(f)[0]
```

my question is, how to get that form using vue js? thanks for your answer

Comment: usin in html v-on:submit.prevent="save_data" and then in save_data: function(event){ you can access to element by event.currentTarget

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form in vue. How do I reference the form element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996657/submit-a-form-in-vue-how-do-i-reference-the-form-element)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$event` equavalent to javascript `event` ..

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="save_data($event)"></form>

methods: {
   save_data: function(f){
     console.log(f.target); // form element
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the actual form element you can assing it a ref attribute on the HTML like so:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="save_data(this)" ref="myForm"></form>
```

Then in your root instance of Vue you can retrieve the element like so:

```
this.$refs.myForm.$el
```

Comment: In the example OP gave, jquery will return a dom element, so the equivalent would be `this.$refs.myForm.$el`

Comment: @smac89
Correct. Edited answer.